# Как удалить первое слово из переменной в SMARTY

Tags: php, smarty

Как добиться того, чтобы удалить ПЕРВОЕ слово из переменной в SMARTY?
Для примера:
Из "Привет стаковерфлоу, мне нужна помощь" в " стаковерфлоу, мне нужна помощь".

Comment: Строго говоря не является задачей шаблонизатора выполнение подобной логики. По этому правильным ответом было бы - ни как. Хотя возможно как то и можно.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Фактически, как уже сказано в комментариях, такая логика не сосвсем относится к функционалу самого шаблона. Но в общем-то в смарти вы можете использовать любые функции пхп в качестве модификаторов. Основная проблема тут - корректно выделить первое слово, просто средствами пхп, а привести этот код в смарти не сложно.

Например, если использовать `strpbreak` задав ему несколько символов, которые будут ограничивать слова, то задача сведется к такому:

```
{$txt = "Привет стаковерфлоу, мне нужна помощь"}
{$txt|strpbrk:" ,;!"}
```

но это собственно простейший случай, т.к. у нас певое слово отделено лишь пробелом. А вот в случае `Привет, стэковерфлоу` данный модификатор найдет первую запятую и вернет строку начиная с пробела. Но случай с пробелом будет довольно частым, и легко решаем добавлением еще одного модификатора

```
{$txt|strpbrk:" ,;!"|trim}
```

В общем, для начала вам сами надо понять, как и по каким правилам вы хотите вырезать первое слово, а потом уже переносить эту логику в шаблон.